# UWP, Inject touch events Exception

Tags: c#, uwp

Using InputInjector and InjectedInputTouchInfo to programmatically send touch events in windows 10 1709. I have been able to send mouse events using InjectMouseInput. But When I tried to inject touch events, I am getting exception.
Code tried is same as provided by [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection)

```
inputInjector.InjectTouchInput(
            new List<InjectedInputTouchInfo> {
            new InjectedInputTouchInfo {
                Contact = new InjectedInputRectangle
                {
                    Top = 50,
                    Bottom = 50,
                    Left = 40,
                    Right = 40
                },
                PointerInfo = new InjectedInputPointerInfo {
                    PixelLocation = new InjectedInputPoint {
                        PositionX = 40, PositionY = 50
                    },
                    PointerOptions = InjectedInputPointerOptions.PointerUp,
                    PointerId = 1,
                },
                Pressure = 0.0,
                TouchParameters = 
                InjectedInputTouchParameters.Pressure | 
                InjectedInputTouchParameters.Contact
            }
        });
```

executed this code gives exception.

> {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>      at Windows.UI.Input.Preview.Injection.InputInjector.InjectTouchInput(IEnumerable`1 input)
>      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is issue with an update of Windows, Visual Studio or SDK. Your code seem correct.

You can check [[RS:1709][UWP][C#]InputInjector.InjectTouchInput - exception](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79e42018-feef-4745-9afc-020ab387de15/rs1709uwpcinputinjectorinjecttouchinput-exception?forum=wpdevelop) at MSDN Forums.